Terraform passing ipv6_cidr_blocks through dynamic ingress/egress blocks
I have my security group module with dynamic ingres & egress rules:
dynamic "egress" {
  for_each = var.egress_rules_app_layer
  content {
    from_port        = egress.value["from_port"]
    to_port          = egress.value["to_port"]
    protocol         = egress.value["protocol"]
    cidr_blocks      = try((egress.value["cidr_blocks"]),[])
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = try((egress.value["ipv6_cidr_blocks"]),[])
    description      = egress.value["description"]
  } 
}

And I'm passing the rules through tfvars file:
egress_rules_app_layer = [
  {
     from_port   = 443
     to_port     = 443
     protocol    = "tcp"
     description = "https"
     cidr_blocks = [
       "47.60.187.70/32"
     ]
   },
   {
     from_port        = 443
     to_port          = 443
     protocol         = "tcp"
     description      = "https"
     cidr_blocks      = []
     ipv6_cidr_blocks = [
       "2686:4721:4422::6812:2a7a/128"
     ]
   }
]

The issue is that it's not taking my ipv6_cidr_blocks. this is the plan output:
             + {
              + cidr_blocks      = [
                  + "47.60.187.70/32"
                ]
              + description      = "https"
              + from_port        = 443
              + ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
              + prefix_list_ids  = []
              + protocol         = "tcp"
              + security_groups  = []
              + self             = false
              + to_port          = 443
            },
          + {
              + cidr_blocks      = []
              + description      = "https"
              + from_port        = 443
              + ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
              + prefix_list_ids  = []
              + protocol         = "tcp"
              + security_groups  = []
              + self             = false
              + to_port          = 443
            },  

Why it's not taking into consideration ipv6_cidr_blocks only directly through rules or directly inside the security group rule. It's clear that it's not any syntax issue, I isolated the case and retried even with the latest Terraform version. I wasn't able to find any reasonable explanation.

Can you drop the enclosing braces here: try((egress.value["ipv6_cidr_blocks"]),[]) to use try(egress.value["ipv6_cidr_blocks"],[])?

I tried, I tried without luck, I tried other suggestions from chat GPT , I applied the code it simply ignores it. Even if I pass a random string for the ipv6_cidr_blocks it simply ignores it.

Please share the type definition for egress_rules_app_layer as it is likely that the optional is not being used 100% correctly here, and therefore the map is dropping undefined values during resolution (a known issue dating back to 0.12 before the implementation of optional).

Yes thank you Matthew, this was the issue, I can't believe I missed this.
